# How can I pass parameter to event calendar helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using a [event_calendar](https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar)plugin with rails 2.3.8. I have events table with name, venue and trainer columns. I want to color events based on trainer and venue. I could color it by trainer. But now I want to pass parameter to the event calendar helper considering whether it is trainer or venue. How should I pass this parameter? Anybody work with this plugin? plz help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at README.rdoc you'll get

```
  <%= event_calendar %>


==Default Options

The default options for the calendar are:

  defaults = {
    :year => Time.zone.now.year,
    :month => Time.zone.now.month,
    :abbrev => true,
    :first_day_of_week => 0, # See note below when setting this
    :show_today => true,
    :month_name_text => Time.zone.now.strftime("%B %Y"),
    :previous_month_text => nil,
    :next_month_text => nil,
    :event_strips => [],

    # it would be nice to have these in the CSS file
    # but they are needed to perform height calculations
    :width => nil,
    :height => 500, 
    :day_names_height => 18,
    :day_nums_height => 18,
    :event_height => 18,
    :event_margin => 1,
    :event_padding_top => 1,

    :use_all_day => false,
    :use_javascript => true,
    :link_to_day_action => false
  }
```

I take following two parameters in my calendar and override plugin helper method in the

```
<%= event_calendar(user.format, outbound) %>
```

app/helpers/calendar_helper.rb

```
  def event_calendar_opts(display_format, outbound)
    {
      :year => @year,
      :month => @month,
      :abbrev => nil,
      :event_strips => @event_strips,
      :display_properties => (display_format==4)? 4 : 3,
      :outbound => outbound,
      :month_name_text => I18n.localize(@shown_month, :format => "%B %Y"),
      :previous_month_text => month_link(@shown_month.last_month),
      :next_month_text => next_month_link(@shown_month.next_month)    }
  end

  def event_calendar(display_format, outbound)
    # args is an argument hash containing :event, :day, and :options
    index = 0
    calendar event_calendar_opts(display_format, outbound) do |args|
      html << some_html
      html
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can I pass parameter to the vendor\plugins\event_calendar\lib\event_calendar\calendar helper as above? I tried to pass it. But there are errors.

Comment: @Rosh:- Yes you can pass parameter to your plugin's helper method using above method. In my example you can get parameter in plugin's helper like following `options[:display_properties]`. One important nor whenever you change in your plugin do restart our server.